# Is size of page table the same for every process?

Tags: linux, paging, virtual-memory, multi-level

I am learning about virtual memory and paging. Every process has a page table but is the size of every page table the same? Where can I find information about them?

I think they are the same. In multilevel(eg. 2) paging, considering process1 needs 1GB memory and process 2 needs 2GB memory, process1 may need less internel pages. And therefore, multilevel paging will save place.
Am I right?

If they're not the same, why does multilevel paging save place? I think every page is necessary and every 2-level page table in this situation must exist.

Comment: This is more of an OS design question than a programming question. [cs.se] or [unix.se] seem like better places to ask.

Comment: Only top level table (page directory for 32-bit mode without PE or page map level 5 for 64-bit mode) must be the same to cover all virtual address space. All lower level tables may exist or may not. But every table, if exists, on each level has the same size as it covers fixed address range.